# How to get Viewing profile ID in buddypress?

Tags: buddypress, user-meta

I want to get the viewing profle's (another user's profile that current user is viewing) user_id

is there any shortcode or function available for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need this: `bp_displayed_user_id()`.

Also see [playing with the user’s ID in different contexts](http://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/playing-with-the-users-id-in-different-contexts/) in BuddyPress documentation.

Comment: This function is not working for me, I put this into 'functions.php' and always it returning 0.

Comment: probably the portion of code where you are using it doesn't run when a user profile is displayed; so, it makes sense the return value is 0. For istance, using that function in the homepage or in the member directory or some other page would return 0 for sure. Is this your case?

Comment: hmmm NO, I've added it to function.php, as you may aware it will be executed every time the page refreshes or loads. And the test code I,ve put as below ,


echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(".bp_displayed_user_id().");</script>";

Comment: uhm, I was not talking about that...can you paste a portion of the code? Maybe that will help...

Comment: Tha it is the coding part, Its not working, Thank for your time and help @blake83

Comment: blake, a bit more of context in the Answer is always welcomed. Link to the Documentation page of the function, etc. . . . & welcome to WordPress StackExchange :)

Comment: @VicKyAmr you're welcome; I'm sorry I was not helpful :)

Comment: @brasofilo thanks! About the poor answer I'm sorry, you're right! I'll do better next time. ;)

Comment: Don't be sorry, every participation is a great feat. You'll find very nice notifications tools at [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/) and how this community works in the [Meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Welcome aboard and remember that you can always edit/expand you Q&A's.